# Get image url from service and then echo with php

Tags: php

My client set up a tracking pixel to keep their own accounts of how many times a service of theirs is requested. They set up a php service such that, whenever their service is called, I should send a request to a url (`http://ads3.initiative.com.uy/openx/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=3969&amp;cb="{RANDOM_NUMBER}"`)

Calling up that url manually with any random number returns a 1x1 gif image to display.

I inserted this call into my site:

```
<?php
  // Generate random id of min/max length
  $rand_id = rand(1, 10000);

  // Echo the image and append the random string to the url
  echo "<img src='http://ads3.initiative.com.uy/openx/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=3969&amp;cb=".$rand_id."'/>";
?>
```

But it is showing a broken image link (closer inspection shows it is trying to display the url as an image instead of the gif file it returns) and it's probably not registering the call on their end either. All the examples I could find here so far are about echoing an image you already have the url path to - but I need to make sure the call is made and registered on the client end.

I tried using

```
echo "<img src='".$_GET["http://ads3.initiative.com.uy/openx/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=3969&amp;cb=".$rand_id."].'/>
```

with the url there but it didn't fix it.

I'm very new to PHP and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Tested your code and it's fine... your problem is elsewhere.  Show the actual raw HTML output of your PHP.

Comment: Works for me - I get the 1x1 gif. BTW, you can't use $_GET like that ($_GET contains the URL parameters passed to the PHP-script).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a console debugger, you should be able to see that the network traffic is going to the ad provider.  Also, I am seeing a gif image come back.

**gif image**

[image: gif image]

**network traffic to ad provider**

[image: network traffic to ad provider]

Comment: The broken image must be an error elsewhere then. I was afraid I was handling this wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @ConnorU no worries - use your network tab like you see in the debugger image i posted to find the 404 image.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
  // Generate random id of min/max length
  $rand_id = rand(1, 10000);

  // Echo the image and append the random string to the url
  echo "<img src='http://ads3.initiative.com.uy/openx/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=3969&amp;cb=\".$rand_id.\"'/>";
?>
```

Try that code, I have escaped the slash around the variable in your src

Comment: That isn't the problem here... quotes aren't supposed to be in the URL, and even if they were, you'd escape them for the URL.